# How to loop through each line of a file, name the file after the third field, and then take the contents of each line and put it in the file

Tags: bash

Let say I have a file with

this is a cat
this is a dog
this is a bear

I want to loop through this file, read the fourth field, create a file with that name and then push that line through via bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  echo $line
  var1 = `cat $line | awk '{print $4}'`
  echo $line >> ${var1}.txt
done < animals.txt
```

would want file called cat.txt with line this is a cat and so on

Comment: Is there any way you can make your question a bit more clear? If i'm understanding correctly you want to take every 4th word? and create a file whos name is that 4th word with the previous 3 words (including the 4th) as the files' content?

Comment: Yes that is what im trying to do

Comment: Are there supposed to be newlines between the sentences in the input file?  Or is it supposed to be all one line?  My answer below answers your question as written (and it provides the fixes to your syntax which may be standing in your way of just solving this yourself).  But line vs string parsing in bash is very different, so you have to clarify your question.

Comment: I will test it out and then grant you credit if correct.  Thx

Comment: I have granted you credit for the solution.  I appreciate the great support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two specific issues, but you're not *that* far off.

1) `cat` is for files, not bash variables.  You can use `echo` for bash variables.

2) the assignment operator `=` can't have any space to the left of it in bash.

So your line 6 now looks like this:

```
  var1=`echo $line | awk '{print $4}'`
```

After that change, on my system, this produces a file called `cat.txt` which has the same text as the single line in `animals.txt`

```
$ ls
animals.txt  q.sh
$ cat animals.txt 
this is a cat this is a dog this is a bear
$ cat q.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  echo $line
  var1=`echo $line | awk '{print $4}'`
  echo $line >> ${var1}.txt
done < animals.txt
$ bash q.sh
this is a cat this is a dog this is a bear
$ cat cat.txt 
this is a cat this is a dog this is a bear
```